# Intern/WD: Can't get execution of javascript in remote browser to work

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, intern

I'm growing desperate about what should be a simple problem.

Executing:

```
    bdd.it('works', function() {
        return this.remote
            .get(require.toUrl(testPageUrl))
            .waitForElementByCssSelector(readyToken, 50000)
            .execute(function(){2 + 2});
    });
```

gives me:

```
Error: Failed to execute execute(function () {
            __cov_VwMr0JS3ESfzTM8YeWV7lg.f['4']++;
            __cov_VwMr0JS3ESfzTM8YeWV7lg.s['7']++;
            2 + 2;
        }): Error response status: 13.  __cov_VwMr0JS3ESfzTM8YeWV7lg is not defined
```

Which I do not understand at all - what are these strange increments?

Executing:

```
    bdd.it('works', function() {
        return this.remote
            .get(require.toUrl(testPageUrl))
            .waitForElementByCssSelector(readyToken, 50000)
            .execute('2 + 2', function (err, res) {

            });
    });
```

Gives me:

```
Error: Failed to execute execute("2 + 2", function (err, res) {
            __cov_VwMr0JS3ESfzTM8YeWV7lg.f['4']++;
        }): Error response status: 13.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it now. Two different problems were involved:

1. The code coverage component of intern (I guess Istanbul) did inject its code into the remote javascript which is the explanation for the strange increment statements which of course can not be understood by the browser. So disabling the code coverage tool is necessary.
2. The correct way to define a callback is:

   ```
   bdd.it('works', function() {
       return this.remote
           .get(require.toUrl(testPageUrl))
           .execute(function() {
               return 3;
           })
           .then(function(result) {
               expect(result).to.equal(3);
           });
   });
   ```

Hope it may help somebody at some point.

Best regards